# Add ability to embed video inside a question or answer

Tags: feature-request

This came up on another [meta.stackexchange](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137/please-add-support-for-embedded-youtube-videos) site.  This would be super helpful for automotive as pictures and video (with sound) are important to diagnosing a problem.  Without sound, you use a diagnostic tool.

For example, for my issue with power steering, my car makes a very distinct sound when the wheel is turned.  I think someone could help out very quickly if they could hear what I hear.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that embedding videos, at least YouTube videos, would prove to be an asset.

As of today, there are:

- [79 questions](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A*youtube.com*%20is%3Aquestion) linking to youtube.com
- [38 questions](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A*youtu.be*%20is%3Aquestion) linking to youtu.be
- [137 answers](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A*youtube.com*%20is%3Aanswer) linking to youtube.com
- [69 answers](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A*youtu.be*%20is%3Aanswer) linking to youtu.be

I think it's high time we asked for this feature for mech.SE.

Comment: Is this feature available on other SE sites?

Comment: @DucatiKiller yes it is

Comment: well then, it seems totally reasonable to request for the feature to be here.  I totally agree with you on this for sure.  Would be super beneficial in some cases.

Comment: The last response has some embedded video.  I haven't seen any on SE until this one today.   Looks good, as you would expect.    http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112998/why-does-everyone-think-that-the-millennium-falcon-is-a-piece-of-junk

Comment: How did you get those numbers?

Comment: @DucatiKiller click on the links to see the queries. The number is reported in the top right corner of the search results

Comment: Related, in that there's a potentially useful SEDE query here for comparison: http://meta.woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/287/enable-youtube-embeds-for-woodworking

Comment: Also, btw, [you can embed thumbnails with a little trick](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66397/provide-a-way-to-embed-videos-in-answers/263626#263626).

Answer (score 4):

I'm not clear on why embedding the video is critical.  I'm always happy to have still shots and I'm certainly not averse to an annotated link pointing at the video (on Youtube or wherever).  On the other hand, I absolutely do not want any sort of player or animation that starts up against my will on any Stack site ever.

Somewhat related: I spend a large amount of my time in an environment where bandwidth restrictions prevent access to Youtube and the like, so all I'd see in those boxes would be blanks or "This site has been blocked."

Comment: The Youtube embeds don't auto-play and don't load the video until you click play, they're quite unobtrusive (aside from the big embed box)

Comment: I think the ability to embed videos is especially useful for this SE site. Still shots will not always convey the problems/solutions

Answer (score 0):

I think videos can be an excellent way of assisting users and a valuable tool in some cases.

Video has become a component of life for a large swath of the global population over the last several years.  [1.5 million Droid based phones are being activated daily](http://www.androidcentral.com/larry-page-15-million-android-devices-activated-every-day) among the wireless carriers!

I think it only makes sense to have a better video support mechanism as a tool.  What the OP cannot explain properly could be easily conveyed with 45 seconds of video.

I know @bobcross was concerned with an autoplay feature effecting users that are accessing the site from secure and bandwidth restricted corporate environments, I went to the sci-fi SE site and none of their videos were set for autoplay.  I don't see this as an issue simply because the verbiage will still be the primary vehicle in delivering the question and describing the attributes of the issue.  The video as a simple add-on, in cases where it's relevant.

Another benefit to video is that SEO (search engine optimization) has an attribute for displayed video.  Displayed video in websites helps the drive the ranking of a site higher, at least in Google's last few iterations of their SEO algorithm.

I think there are multiple benefits to enabling this feature.

- Assisting in troubleshooting
- Being current
- SEO optimization