# What's the possibility of having stack exchange support media beyond images?

Tags: feature-request

A lot of MVM&R questions could go a lot further if folks were able to upload a video or audio clip. I realize folks could use YouTube for something like that and link to it here but certain communities in the StackExchange network I believe could really benefit from multimedia possibilities.

Comment: I like how you got around the use of videos :o) Very clever.

Comment: Got out my tripod for this one, needed that stability because I was planning on these [animated gifs](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1902/animated-gifs-for-user-content)

Answer (score 5):

This has come up before:

[Add ability to embed video inside a question or answer](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/169/57)

My latest concerns about videos have to do with curation:

1. Are we now going to be reviewing videos as answers?
2. If an answer is just an embedded video, is that a valid answer?  Or should the text stand on its own without the video at all?
3. Of the video is embedded, are we now responsible for its content?  Do I need to watch a 40 minute video to find the racial slur at minute 37?

My position continues to be that answers should stand on their own. Static images and explanatory text makes for long lasting robust content. A linked video with words explaining why it is a useful addition to the rest of the text is a valuable tool but it does not stand on its own.

Comment: A linked URL of a video or audio clip serves as good as having them embedded. I see no compelling reason to do anything differently than we are now.